# Failure to resolve hostnames on local network

Tags: networking

I am having a problem with name resolution on just one machine.  Up until recently, the machine was running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with KDE.  I attempted to upgrade it to 22.04 yesterday, but had a power failure during the upgrade that rendered the machine unbootable.  So it's now running a clean install of Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.  The problem is the same after the new install.

The specific problem is that the machine periodically gets into a state where DNS queries for hostnames on my local network are failing with the following error message.  Note that external hostnames resolve fine all the time, even when local names are failing.  Also, note that the failure occurs whether I use the short hostname or the FQDN:

Temporary failure in name resolution

At a first glance, this seems like a misconfiguration, but it works fine after a reboot. Also running "sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved" will correct the problem for a period of time.  After the machine has been running for a while, though, the problem returns.

On the earlier version, I had jumped through about a dozen hoops, trying different things and finally stumbled onto something that worked reliably.  If I am reading my own notes correctly, it looks like I ended up disabling systemd-resolved and configured the machine to use NetworkManager.  I am not enthusiastic about doing that again, so I am interested in actually understanding the root problem.

My DHCP server assigns two DNS server addresses, one to my local DNS server and one to 8.8.8.8.  My theory is that it was somehow getting into a state where it was only using 8.8.8.8, so I configured /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns_servers.conf to use only my local DNS server.  That did not help.

That would suggest a problem with my internal DNS server (which is running Windows 2008 R2 as a domain controller).  The thing is, I have about 20 devices - including several other Linux machines - and they all work fine.  It is only one machine that has this problem.

I would be interested in understanding if there is a systematic way to understand what pieces are involved in name resolution, so that I could determine exactly where the failure is occurring so that I can permanently correct it.  Now is a good time to do this, since the installation is completely as installation left it, except for the dns_servers.conf change that I mentioned.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Wade

Comment: I've done some more research on this.  I've learned to enable journal logging for systemd-resolved, which is helping.  I've also learned the following command line to see which DNS server is currently in use:

resolvectl status

Using that command gives me the following output that confirms my suspicion above that systemd-resolved is switching to 8.8.8.8 when the problem occurs.  When it works correctly, it is using my local DNS server.

Now I just need to figure out why it's switching to the external DNS (and why my dns_servers.conf override isn't working).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that works.

It's been a little bit of a frustrating experience, because I've read dozens of articles about overriding the DNS name servers via configuration files.  None of them worked.  It seems that changes to the config files apply to the Global properties, but not the properties for the specific link.  I was not able to find a reference to change the properties for a specific link.  It would be nice if there were a canonical reference for how resolved works, but I've not found such a thing.

Anyway, what finally worked was to use the Connections UI in the System Settings app.  I changed method in the IPV4 properties for the connection from "Automatic" to "Automatic (Only Addresses)" and added only the IP for my home DNS server in the "DNS Servers" box.

It took a while to realize that this was the solution because it does not seem to take effect when you hit the "Apply" button.  It also seems that restarting the systemd-resolved doesn't cause it to take effect either.  At least "resolvectl status" still shows the 8.8.8.8 address.  The change only appeared after a full reboot.  I suppose that there is a way to do it without a reboot, but I could not find out which service or process needed to be restarted.